# Create merged column and index column from 2 similar columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like this: `{"Val1": [...], "Val2": [...]}`
What I now want to achieve is a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
{
    "Vals": [<should contain all vals from Val1 and Val2>], 
    "type": [<1 or 2 depending on the column from which 
              the corresponding value originated>]
}
```

I could generate this by eg:

```
new = DataFrame({"vals": old.vals1.values + old.vals2.values,
                 "type": ([1] * len(old)) + ([2] * len(old))})
```

But this feels very hacky, and I wonder whether there is an elegant one-liner using a pandas method. Because in my actual problem the table has 4 more columns and then my hacky solutions becomes quite typing intensive.

EDIT:
A concrete example would be:

```
old = pd.DataFrame({"A": [2, 4, 5], "B": [1, 2, 3], "C":[4, 5, 6]})
new = pd.DataFrame({"A": [2, 4, 5, 2, 4, 5], "B and C": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], "type": (["B"] * 3) + (["C"] * 3)})

old:

    A   B   C
0   2   1   4
1   4   2   5
2   5   3   6

new:
    A   B and C     type
0   2   1           B
1   4   2           B
2   5   3           B
3   2   4           C
4   4   5           C
5   5   6           C
```

Comment: Would be great if you could share some sample input with expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'val1':[1,2,3,4],'val2':[5,6,7,8]})
```

Using [`pd.melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.melt.html) you'll get what you want:

```
df.melt(var_name='Type', value_name='vals')
      Type    vals
0     val1      1
1     val1      2
2     val1      3
3     val1      4
4     val2      5
5     val2      6
6     val2      7
7     val2      8
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
datadict = {
        'Val1': [1,3,5,7,9],
        'Val2': [2,4,6,8,10],
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(datadict)

df = pd.melt(df,var_name='Val')
print (df)  
    Val  value
0  Val1      1
1  Val1      3
2  Val1      5
3  Val1      7
4  Val1      9
5  Val2      2
6  Val2      4
7  Val2      6
8  Val2      8
9  Val2     10
```